# Adding space between Radio button and Label in selectOneRadio in jsf

Tags: css, jsf, selectoneradio

can any one advice on adding a space between a radio button and its label.

do we have any attributes in f:selectItem for doing this

I have to align the radios to the other components of the page. My Labels are aligned but to align the radio, I need to put some space between it and the labels.

I am unable to find any attribute to help me in this.

Please help.

Comment: You already gave the answer yourself in the tags: use CSS. Just put `padding: 10px` on the label or so. The only attribute you need to know about is `styleClass`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I recently did this, using primefaces:

```
<p:column headerText="Is your hair naturally blonde?" width="140">
        <p:selectOneRadio value="#{mybean.haircolor}" id="haircolor" layout="custom">
            <f:selectItem itemValue="true" />
            <f:selectItem itemValue="false" />
        </p:selectOneRadio>

        <p:panelGrid columns="2">
            <h:panelGroup>
            <p:radioButton id="hairColorYes" for="haircolor" itemIndex="0"/>
             <h:outputLabel for="hairColorYes" value="Yes" styleClass="radiolabelPF"/>
            </h:panelGroup>
            <h:panelGroup>
            <p:radioButton id="hairColorNo" for="haircolor" itemIndex="1"/>
            <h:outputLabel for="hairColorNo" value="No" styleClass="radiolabelPF"/>
            </h:panelGroup>  
         </p:panelGrid>
 </p:column>
```

and then my one CSS style:

```
.radiolabelPF {
  margin-left: 5px;  
}
```

The trick was to use layout="custom" in `<p:selectOneRadio>`. My actual radio buttons and labels are within the `<h:panelGroup>` tags.

This was the only way I could control the space between the radio label and button in Primefaces. It's also documented in the "custom layout" section of the documentation on selectOneRadio.

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/oneRadio.xhtml

Comment: Uh, you can just override default radio button layout using CSS? No need for a custom radio button layout.

Comment: I tried that but got nowhere, i.e setting the margin for `input[type="radio"]`  in my css. After several hours the custom layout was the only way that worked.

Comment: Just do `.ui-selectoneradio label { margin-left: 5px; }` ? See also generated HTML output in browser's F12

Comment: `<p:selectOneRadio value="#{accident.fatality}" id="accidentFatality" >
                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Yes" itemValue="true" />
                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="No" itemValue="false" />
                                    </p:selectOneRadio>` with `.ui-selectoneradio label { margin-left: 5px; }` didn't work.

Comment: Then you've a localized problem (you've other custom styles) or are using an older PF version for which different CSS selector may be needed. At least, this all is definitely unnecessary.

Comment: I'm using PF 5.3.

Answer (score -1):

Please use CSS styles for this task - please see [this tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_list.asp) for examples